# How to view incorrectly recognized text

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, text-classification

There is a neural network that classifies the sentiment of the reviews. The accuracy is not 100%, hence there are texts that are recognized by the network incorrectly. How can I see them? I tried my function, but it gives an error

```
    data = pd.concat([positive_train_data,negative_train_data,positive_test_data,negative_test_data],ignore_index = True)
    data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    x = data.Text
    y = data.Sentiment

    x_train, x_test, y_train1, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.50, random_state = 2000)
    print( "Train set has total {0} entries with {1:.2f}% negative, {2:.2f}% positive".format(len(x_train),
                                                                                 (len(x_train[y_train1 == 0]) / (len(x_train)*1.))*100,
                                                                                (len(x_train[y_train1 == 1]) / (len(x_train)*1.))*100))

    print ("Test set has total {0} entries with {1:.2f}% negative, {2:.2f}% positive".format(len(x_test),
                                                                                 (len(x_test[y_test == 0]) / (len(x_test)*1.))*100,
                                                                                (len(x_test[y_test == 1]) / (len(x_test)*1.))*100))

    tvec1 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10000,ngram_range=(1, 2),min_df=3,use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1,stop_words = 'english')
    tvec1.fit(x_train)
    x_train_tfidf = tvec1.transform(x_train)
    print(x_test.shape)
    x_test_tfidf = tvec1.transform(x_test).toarray()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=10000))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
optimiz = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = optimiz ,metrics = ['accuracy'])
hist  = model.fit(x_train_tfidf,y_train1,validation_data = (x_test_tfidf,y_test ),epochs = 5,batch_size = 64)
```

And my function

```
y_pred_vect = model.predict(x_test_tfidf)
# bolean mask
mask = (y_pred_vect != y_test).any(axis=1)
print(mask)
print(len(mask))
num_words=5000 # only use top 1000 words
INDEX_FROM=3   # word index offset
# этот шаг нужен чтобы получить `test_x` в изначальном виде (до токенизации):
(train_x, _), (test_x, _) = imdb.load_data(num_words=num_words, index_from=INDEX_FROM)
x_wrong = test_x[mask]

word_to_id = imdb.get_word_index()
word_to_id = {k:(v+INDEX_FROM) for k,v in word_to_id.items()}
word_to_id["<PAD>"] = 0
word_to_id["<START>"] = 1
word_to_id["<UNK>"] = 2

id_to_word = {value:key for key,value in word_to_id.items()}
all_wrong_sents = [' '.join(id_to_word[id] for id in sent) for sent in x_wrong]
print(all_wrong_sents[:10])
```

Error on line - 
mask = (y_pred_vect != y_test).any(axis=1)

Data must be 1-dimensional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.squeeze(y_pred_vect) != y_test
```

Comment: now No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Remove the .any(axis=1)

Comment: Oh, it seems to work, thanks! And you do not know how I can submit my own text to the web for verification?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, please elaborate.

Comment: Let's say I want to check with my network the sentence "This movie is fine" and the program should produce the result pos or neg

Comment: You might be able to validate that your network is working properly by using this to benchmark https://stride.ai/texsie/